# How do I format my user input as 1. "integer", 2. "integer" and not make the code run all over again?

Tags: python

What my code does is that it runs the code all over again, and it should just ask the user to not type a string or such, only integers without running the code all over again. This is problematic because if the user would want to sort 50 integers and accidentally mistypes a string, then the user would have to start over again...

I have tried several try and catch code but doesn't seem to work.

```
list1 = []

def bubble_sort():
    numbers = input("How many numbers do you want to sort: ")
    try:
        values = int(numbers)
        print("\nEnter your values: ") 
        for k in range (values):
            list1.append(int(input()))
        print("\nUnsorted list: ", list1)
        for j in range(len(list1)-1,0,-1):
            for i in range(j):
                if list1[i] > list1[i+1]:
                    list1[i], list1[i+1] = list1[i+1], list1[i]
        print("\nSorted list: ", list1)

    except ValueError:
        print("\nThat's not an int!\n")
        bubble_sort()


bubble_sort()
```

Comment: could you change the question title, so that people with a similar problem might also fond your question?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
list1 = []

def bubble_sort():
    numbers = input("How many numbers do you want to sort: ")

    values = int(numbers)
    print("\nEnter your values: ") 
    while len(list1) < values:
        try:
            list1.append(int(input()))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nThat's not an int!\n")
    print("\nUnsorted list: ", list1)
    for j in range(len(list1)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(j):
            if list1[i] > list1[i+1]:
                list1[i], list1[i+1] = list1[i+1], list1[i]
    print("\nSorted list: ", list1)
```

This solution changes the scope of the exception so that, after the exception is handled, the code resumes in the appropriate place (instead of running all of bubble_sort again).